# Testing Silverlight Application in other PC without configuring IIS

Tags: c#, silverlight, web-deployment

Newbie here. I have created a Silverlight App which retrieves data via WCF RIA Services. Now I would like test it to another PC so I did a Publish. The folder contains bin, ClientBin (with xap), .html, .config, etc.

I then copied the folder to the other PCe and opened the *.html file

My silverlight app didn't run. Do I really need to configure the IIS for the other machine and deploy the binaries there to see my silverlight application in action?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want simply to watch Silverlight UI (without using WCF) you can, of cource, open *.html page with the application. But if your application needs in WCF service, the service should be runned.
If your machines in domain group and you have IIS installed for one of them, you can in Visual Studio in project properties configure use local IIS insted of developers web-server, then you should update service references and then you can browse silverlight app. from within any computer in domain network.

Comment: I see. I have tried opening the *.html but my app is not loading (up to 100% only). Perhaps I need to configure IIS and deploy the WCF. Thanks.